# How to use google speech to text API without SSL?

Tags: api, speech-to-text

I am trying to use speech to text api on my esp8266 using this address .But i am getting that error .How can I solve that ?

```
http://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize?key={API_KEY}
```

> "code": 403,
>
> "message": "SSL is required to perform this operation.",
>
> "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"

Comment: Use `https://`, i.e. `https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize?key={API_KEY}`

Comment: It isn't possible to use https:// with esp8266 as I am using http request.

Comment: You might want to use `WiFiClientSecure` connecting to port 443 in this case, since google API requires you to use https connection